# My app is messsed up in landscape view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
              android:id="@+id/adView"    
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
              ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
              android:background="#E5E4E2"
    />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_topkniga" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ed620b"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="25sp"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/textHint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="6" 
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#e5802d"
            android:text="@string/btnAskQ"     
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in portrait view my app looks perfect:

[image]

But in landscape the `EditText` is just gone:

[image]

Why is this happening? What am I missing here? I know that it a super small part, but I can't spot it.

Comment: It's behind your button.

Comment: @DroidBender Ok, but How can I fit it in the screen?

Comment: The height of landscape view is limiting the content that can be viewed.

Comment: You can use `scollview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                android:background="#E5E4E2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"
                android:src="@drawable/rsz_topkniga" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ed620b"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/textHint"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="6"
                android:background="#ffffff"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e5802d"
        android:text="@string/btnAskQ"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it says: `Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log`

Comment: "ScrollView" containt only one child so if you have more child in "ScrollView" then you have to put all those in one parent layout and set this parent layout as child of "ScrollView"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scollview` outside of `LinearLayout`. This will allow the content inside the `LinearLayout` scrollable and hence viewable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
          android:id="@+id/adView"    
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
          ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
          android:background="#E5E4E2"
/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"
    android:src="@drawable/rsz_topkniga" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ed620b"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="25sp"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/textHint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="6" 
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#e5802d"
        android:text="@string/btnAskQ"     
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply put ur whole layout under scrollview. 
Edit-

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">
```

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
          android:id="@+id/adView"    
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
          ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
          android:background="#E5E4E2"
/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"
    android:src="@drawable/rsz_topkniga" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ed620b"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="25sp"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/textHint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="6" 
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the scrollview, maybe just try to keep the views above your button:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/btnAsk"
android:orientation="vertical">
```